# Dynamic cron Magento

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7, cron

How can I set up cron time on config.xml on my module to Magento?

Something like:

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <captcha_delete_old_attempts>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr><!--dynamic info here--></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>captcha/observer::deleteOldAttempts</model>
                </run>
            </captcha_delete_old_attempts>
            <captcha_delete_expired_images>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr><!--dynamic info here--></cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>captcha/observer::deleteExpiredImages</model>
                </run>
            </captcha_delete_expired_images>

        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamically set the cron via below code

```
<crontab>
<jobs>
  <module_name>
      <schedule>
          <cron_expr>23 9 * * *</cron_expr>
        </schedule>
        <run>
            <model>module name/model name::function name</model>
        </run>
   </module_name>
 </jobs>
</crontab>
```

using that below link you just check the cron dynamic timings
https://crontab.guru/